# How to determine right value for innodb_sync_array_size

Tags: mysql, concurrency, database-tuning, waits

How do I determine the right value for innodb_sync_array_size in MySQL? We have version 5.7 deployed on AWS RDS with 32 vCPUs, and it sees about 26 concurrent threads on average. When I measure waits using:
 `show engine innodb mutex`, the total number of waits increases by about 143k / hour.

The MySQL documentation does say that a higher number will help with high concurrency and wait situation, but I cannot find any documentation on what to set this number and how to determine whether this will indeed help me.

Comment: Are you getting a lot of "waiting threads"?  (I have not heard of anyone changing it from `1`.)

Comment: @RickJames How do I measure "waiting threads"? Pretty much all the Percona webinar slides have the value set to 16 and they say it should be 16, but don't give an explanation either.

Comment: The AWS documentation at https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/best-practices-for-configuring-parameters-for-amazon-rds-for-mysql-part-1-parameters-related-to-performance/ also recommends it.

My Load Avg 1 min chart shows the count reaching in the range of 14 - 16 on a regular basis. It's still <32 (vCPU). Not sure whether I'd get any performance gains or wait time reduction though.

Answer (score -3):

This might [help](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/best-practices-for-configuring-parameters-for-amazon-rds-for-mysql-part-1-parameters-related-to-performance/) in understanding it more in details.